# minimum number in a string should be 1 regex validation?

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which I need to match. Meaning it should only contains a number followed by space or just a number and minimum number should be 1 always. For ex:

```
3 1 2
1 p 3
6 3 2
0 3 2
```

First and third are valid string and all other are not.

I came up with below regex but I am not sure how can I check for minimum number in that string should be 1 always?

```
str.matches("(\\d|\\s)+")
```

Regex used from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545579/read-inputs-using-scanner-and-parse-all-the-lines-accordingly?noredirect=1#comment95891950_54545579)

Comment: *I came up with below regex*... [Is that so...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545579/read-inputs-using-scanner-and-parse-all-the-lines-accordingly?noredirect=1#comment95891950_54545579)

Comment: can any number be a double digit or negative number?

Comment: @shmosel sorry let me add your link in the question.wanted to make it simple so thats why i didnt added your link. will do now

Comment: @Kartik no it can't.

Comment: Are you trying to match 3 digits in a row?

Comment: it can have more than 3 digits.. not just 3 digits.. just a number or a number followed by space and then another number.

Comment: Try [`^(?:[1-9] ?)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/7NJIA3/1)

Comment: Err, and your numbers are all smaller than 10?! You should start by clarifying your requirements. Are you talking about single digits only, or *numbers*? A number can easily contain a 0 digit. Would "10 11 12" be a valid line?

Comment: no numbers are not smaller than 10. yes thats a valid line.

Comment: \b\d+\s\b|\b\d+\b

Comment: Then you should edit your question to make that really clear.

Comment: @GhostCat OP replied to your comment that numbers are always smaller than 10, but then says that `10 11 12` is a valid line. Should we vote to close?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `\\d` with `[1-9]`.

`\\d` is just a shorthand for the class `[0-9]`.

This is a better regex though: `([1-9]\\s)*[1-9]$`, as it takes care of double digit issues and won't allow space at the end.

Comment: What about "10 3 5" then?

Comment: @GhostCat I was in the middle of creating a better regex. I've added that to the answer. :)

Comment: is it `\s`? not sure

Comment: @flash would be double slash when you put it in a java string.. single otherwise

Comment: The OP just confirmed that he has numbers to check, not digits. So excluding 0 doesn't work at all.

Comment: You only need to exclude 0 as the first (or only?) digit: `([1-9]\d*|\s)+`

Comment: @GhostCat I asked in the question comments "*can any number be a double digit or negative number?*", to which the OP replied "*@Kartik no it can't.*". I guess they themselves are confused.

Comment: @shmosel the title says "*minimum number in a string should be 1...*" so I think it's not just about the first digit only

Comment: Actually I put in a close vote 30 minutes ago. And then I wrote my own answer. Arg. That happens when you come here in the middle of night...

Comment: Minimum number, not minimum digit.

Comment: @shmosel sure, but then according to my clarification in the comments, *double digit* numbers are not allowed.. so minimum number = minimum digit

Comment: He also said *numbers are not [necessarily] smaller than 10*, so I'm guessing he was replying to the negative part.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything can or should be solved with regular expressions.

You could use a simple expression like

```
str.matches("((\\d+)\\s)+")
```

or something alike to simply check that your input line contains only groups of digits followed by one or more spaces.

If that matches, you split along the spaces and for each group of digits you turn it into a number and validate against the valid range.

I have a gut feeling that regular expressions are actually not sufficient for the kind of validation you need.

Answer (score 0):

If it should only contains a number followed by space or just a number and minimum number should be 1 and number can also be larger than 10 you might use:

```
^[1-9]\\d*(?: [1-9]\\d*)*$
```

Note that if you want to match a space only, instead of using `\s` which [matches more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) you could just add a space in the pattern.

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `[1-9]\\d*` Match a number from 1 up
- `(?: [1-9]\\d*)*` Repeat a number from 1 up with a prepended space
- `$` Assert end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Nf6or/1)

Answer (score -1):

Regex is part of the solution. But I don't think that regex alone can solve your problem.

This is my proposed solution:

```
private static boolean isValid(String str) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[(\\d+)\\s]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    return matcher.matches() && Arrays.stream(Arrays.stream(matcher.group().split(" "))
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .toArray()).min().getAsInt() == 1;
}
```

Pay attention to the mathing type: matcher.matches() - to check match against the entire input. (don't use matcher.find() - because it will not reject invalid input such as "1 p 2")